# How to resolve IIdentity for SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, signalr

I am using structureMap for injecting dependencies, I'd like to know 
Which implementation should I provide for IIdentity in SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, SignalR uses the already existing authentication, so you  just authenticate users as you would normally in an ASP.NET application, and you can have hubs or specific hub methods that have the `Authorize` attribute. 
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization

> SignalR does not provide any features for authenticating users. Instead, you integrate the SignalR features into the existing authentication structure for an application. You authenticate users as you would normally in your application, and work with the results of the authentication in your SignalR code. For example, you might authenticate your users with ASP.NET forms authentication, and then in your hub, enforce which users or roles are authorized to call a method. In your hub, you can also pass authentication information, such as user name or whether a user belongs to a role, to the client.

Hope this helps! Good luck!